# showDialog bug: dialog isn't triggered from PopupMenuButton in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, android-alertdialog

I am not able to get `showDialog` work with `PopupMenuButton`. In the example below, there is a button with triggering a dialog to display and a popupmenu too triggering a dialog to display.

The button works but on clicking on the *Alert* text in PopupMenu, the same doesn't happen.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('showDialog bug'), actions: [
          PopupMenuButton(
              itemBuilder: (ctx) => [
                    PopupMenuItem(
                        child: Text('Alert'),
                        onTap: () {
                          showDialog(
                              context: context,
                              builder: (ctx) => AlertDialog(
                                    title: Text('test dialog'),
                                  ));
                        })
                  ])
        ]),
        body: ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              showDialog(
                  context: context,
                  builder: (ctx) => AlertDialog(
                        title: Text('test dialog'),
                      ));
            },
            child: Text('click me')));
  }
}
```

However, when I add another block of `showDialog` subsequent to it, it starts working.

```dart
showDialog(
context: context,
builder: (ctx) => AlertDialog(
      title: Text('test dialog'),
    ));
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

It's not a bug. As I remember, the `onTap` callback of `PopupMenuItem` calls `Navigator.pop` to close the Popup. In that case, when you tap on the `PopupMenuItem` and call `showDialog`, the Dialog will be popped immediately, and leaves the Popup open.

In order to overcome that, you may try this solution :

```
PopupMenuItem(
  child: const Text('Alert'),
  onTap: () {
    Future.delayed(
      const Duration(seconds: 0),
      () => showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) => const AlertDialog(
          title: Text('test dialog'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  },
)
```

Answer (score 16):

There is an easier way to achieve it using the actual functionality of `PopupMenuButton`.

Just give a `value` to you `PopUpMenuItem` and check for it on the `onSelected` callback from `PopupMenuButton` as follows:

```
PopupMenuButton<String>(
  onSelected: (value) async {
    switch (value) {
      case 'open_dialog':
        return showDialog(...);
      default:
        throw UnimplementedError();
    }
  },
  itemBuilder: (context) => [
    const PopupMenuItem(
      child: Text('Open dialog'),
      value: 'open_dialog',
    ),
  ],
),
```

This way you will consume the `parent context` and not the `itemBuilder context` that gets popped on tap as [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69939955/4310067). Then decide what to execute when that value is received, for example, opening the dialog.

You can also use an `enum` instead of `String` as values if you want to have it properly type safe.

Comment: This should be the best answer.

Comment: Perfect answer! Yeah using an `enum` makes this approach more robust.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
PopupMenuItem(
  value: val,
  child: InkWell(
    onTap: opendialog() ?? () {},
    child: Container(
      height: 20,
      child: Row(
        children: [
          AppText(
            text: "Text",
            color: Colors.black38,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```

Comment: See "[answer]" and [Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". While this might be technically correct, it doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be the selected answer. We should educate along with helping solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I just ended wrapping my `PopupMenuItem` child in a `GestureDetector` and leveraging the onTap from there.

```dart
PopupMenuItem<int>(
  enabled: true,
  value: 0,
  child: GestureDetector(
    onTap: () {
      showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) => const ConnectionDialog(),
      );
    },
    child: Row(
      children: [
        Icon(
          Icons.swap_calls,
          color: Theme.of(context)
              .colorScheme
              .onSecondaryContainer,
        ),
        const SizedBox(
          width: 12,
        ),
        const Text('SELECT DEVICE'),
      ],
    ),
  ),
),
```